# Screen scale factor in XCTest

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I am running UITest in which it's crucial to get the screen scale factor. Usually I've used `UIScreen.main.scale`m but `XCUIScreen.main` does not seem to have `scale` property.
Is it possible to access device scale factor in UITests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed it by adding AccessibilityIdentifier to window in AppDelegate that contains info needed:

```
int scaleFactor = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale] intValue];
self.window.accessibilityIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"windowScale:%d", scaleFactor];
```

And later accessing it and parsing in my tests:

```
var windowsScaleFactor: Int {
        let scaleFactorString = self.windows.firstMatch.identifier
        guard let scaleFactor = Int(scaleFactorString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")) else {
            fatalError("Could not determine window scale factor")
        }
        return scaleFactor
    }
```